# break-word CSS Property Not Working with input tag - value attribute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a button on my page **with limited width**.

The problem is when the text overflow the limited width it's hidden. So I'm trying to break the text to display all the text in the same width.

I've tried the following CSS properties but to no avail:

- `word-break: break-word;`
- `overflow-wrap: break-word;`
- `word-wrap: break-word;`
- `white-space:nowrap;`

All these properties works fine with `div` tags but not with `input` tags.

```css
input { 
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: no-wrap;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Select All Content Boxes">
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `white-space: normal;`

> Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary.

```css
input { 
 display: block;
 color: #fff;
 background: #000;
 width: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 10px auto;
 white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Select All Content Boxes">
```